# StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 not working for value inside (3.5g)

Tags: java

```
if (item.get("title") != null && !item.get("title").toString().isEmpty()) {
    String name = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(item.get("title").toString().trim());
    name = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(name);
    item.put("title", name);
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

actual input is   Colour( 3.5g )

and output is :Color #117 
but need the output same as input

Comment: What is the name without using any escape methods?

Comment: `Colour( 3.5g )` as stated in the question

Comment: So why are you `escap`ing if you want the input and output to be the same?

Comment: I actually doubt that your input is what you expect. I just ran `String name = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("Colour( 3.5g )");
  name = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(name);
  System.out.println(name);` and had no issues at all